# Laravel 5 AuthServiceProvider flow

Tags: laravel-5, authorization, roles

I am new in Laravel so I would need help with my solution of AuthServiceProvider class.

How should I write role control if user can have more than one role?
I have this:

```
$gate->define( 'admin', function ( $user )
{
    return $user->roles()
        ->where( 'name', 'admin' )
        ->orWhere( 'name', 'super_admin' )
        ->first();
} );
```

or wold be better to write

```
$gate->define( 'admin', function ( $user )
{
    foreach( $user->roles as $role )
    {
        if( $role->name == 'admin' || $role->name == 'super_admin' ) return true
    }
    return false;
} );
```

Or is there a better way? Is that query from first example executed once or every time i need to check users role?

Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ready-made packages for role and different types of permission. Here is some packages that I have used.

https://github.com/romanbican/roles

https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it.